# Cannot set data fetched from Firebase Database using provider Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch data (List of Object/Dictionaries) from my fierbase database but I'm not able to set the state using provider.

This is my firebase database structure:

```
historical_data: [
  {key: val, key: val, ...},
  {key: val, key: val, ...},
  ...
],
live_data: {
  key: val,
  key: val,
  ...
}
```

Provider file:

```
class StockProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<ChartHistoricalData> _histChartData = [];
  List<ChartHistoricalData> get histChartData => _histChartData;

  Future<void> fetchHistoricalStockData(ref) async {
    await ref.once().then((DataSnapshot data) {
      print(data.value['historical_data']); // Working at this point, I can see my list of objects.
      _histChartData = List<ChartHistoricalData>.from(data
          .value['SBIN_Historical']
          .map((x) => ChartHistoricalData.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList());
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

My model class:

```
class ChartHistoricalData {
  DateTime? x; //DateTime
  double? open;
  double? high;
  double? low;
  double? close;

  ChartHistoricalData(
      {required this.x,
      required this.open,
      required this.high,
      required this.low,
      required this.close});

  ChartHistoricalData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    x = DateTime.parse(json['date']); //date of type string coming from firebase db
    open = json['open'];
    high = json['high'];
    low = json['low'];
    close = json['close'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['date'] = this.x;
    data['open'] = this.open;
    data['high'] = this.high;
    data['low'] = this.low;
    data['close'] = this.close;
    return data;
  }
}
```

The main screen:

```
class SBINChart extends StatefulWidget {
  const SBINChart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChartState createState() => _ChartState();
}

class _ChartState extends State<Chart> {
  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ref = fb.reference();
    context.read<StockProvider>().fetchHistoricalStockData(ref);
    print(context.watch<StockProvider>().histChartData); // Empty
    ...
```

The Error:

```
/flutter ( 4730): [{date: 2021-01-01, high: 280.0, low: 274.4, close: 279.4, open: 274.9}, {date: 2021-01-04, high: 283.9, low: 277.75, close: 281.05, open: 281.85}, {date: 2021-01-05, high: 282.45, low: 277.0, close: 281.75, open: 278.05}, {date: 2021-01-06, high: 289.15, low: 281.4, close: 285.05, open: 283.0}, {date: 2021-01-07, high: 291.8, low: 287.0, close: 287.7, open: 289.0}, {date: 2021-01-08, high: 291.4, low: 285.2, close: 286.0, open: 290.1}, {date: 2021-01-11, high: 288.2, low: 279.6, close: 282.5, open: 288.0}, {date: 2021-01-12, high: 293.85, low: 277.9, close: 292.5, open: 280.0}, {date: 2021-01-13, high: 308.0, low: 294.5, close: 306.8, open: 296.0}, {date: 2021-01-14, high: 309.25, low: 303.8, close: 307.25, open: 306.7}, {date: 2021-01-15, high: 310.9, low: 301.3, close: 303.85, open: 306.8}, {date: 2021-01-18, high: 308.65, low: 292.2, close: 294.45, open: 303.5}, {date: 2021-01-19, high: 302.5, low: 296.4, close: 298.6, open: 297.65}, {date: 2021-01-20, high: 304.7, low: 296.85, close: 302.55, open: 298.8
E/flutter ( 4730): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(103)] Dart Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast, stack trace: #0      StockProvider.fetchHistoricalStockData.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:algoguru/providers/stock_provider.dart:16
E/flutter ( 4730): #1      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:412:31)
E/flutter ( 4730): #2      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:341:26)
E/flutter ( 4730): #3      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:188:27)
E/flutter ( 4730): #4      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
E/flutter ( 4730): #5      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:50:28)
E/flutter ( 4730): #6      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:212:44)
E/flutter ( 4730): #7      StockProvider.fetchHistoricalStockData.<anonymous closure>
package:algoguru/providers/stock_provider.dart:17
E/flutter ( 4730): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4730): #8      StockProvider.fetchHistoricalStockData
package:algoguru/providers/stock_provider.dart:12
E/flutter ( 4730): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I think something can be wrong with the `ChartHistoricalData.fromJson` method, But as i'm new to flutter, I cannot figure out what's wrong. If anyone could help, it would be really great!

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your provider:

```
.map((x) => ChartHistoricalData.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>)));
```

Read the error you are getting carefully. It tells you that it's a type mismatch error, meaning that it expected a certain type which is `Map<String, dynamic>` but you have it something of type `<Object?, Object?>`.

Although they are the same data internally, but only you know that. To dart it doesn't know.
Where did dart get the error `object?` to show it to us? It's from Firebase's package. Because they know it's for sure an object, which could be anything.

But as for you, you told your method that those objects are explicitly going to be String, dynamic. Otherwise, throw an error, which is exactly what happened.

This causes your error. The solution I proposed is called `casting`, where you tell dart, that the variable x we are passing is to be treated as a `Map<String, dynamic>` object, so deal with it and parse it accordingly.

Dart will say okay, cool. But if the object it gets is not a `Map<String, dynamic>` object, it throws a different error saying that what you asked for is not possible because the objects on both sides of the cast are different.

```
Future<void> fetchHistoricalStockData(ref) async {
    await ref.once().then((DataSnapshot data) {
      print(data.value['historical_data']); // Working at this point, I can see my list of objects.
      _histChartData = List<ChartHistoricalData>.from(jsonDecode(data
          .value['SBIN_Historical'])
          .map((x) => ChartHistoricalData.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList());
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed answer, I changed the line with yours, but i'm still getting this error: `[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(103)] Dart Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast,`

Comment: Also add `.toList()` at `ChartHistoricalData.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList());`

Comment: and `print(data.value['SBIN_Historical'])` so we can see what it looks like.

Comment: `data.value['SBIN_Historical']` is a list of objects of length 138, as you can see in the output.

Comment: Try this: 
`.value['SBIN_Historical'] as List<Map<String,dynamic>>` ..the rest of your code

Comment: Error: `type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast,` :(

Comment: I eddited my answer with `jsonDecode`, try that maybe

Comment: Nope, `Dart Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'String',`